# Make Python script open browser and execute HTTP post request

Tags: python-3.x, browser, http-post

I want to send some HTTP POST requests to a website. There's no problem with doing it by my browser, since I'm logged in and I have my authenticated session.
I don't know how to make POST requests by Python while using that authenticated session (so importing data from the browser), and I don't even know if it's possibile, so I thought that I could trigger these POST requests in browser from the Python script.

I know there exists a library called "webbrowser" that allows to make requests by opening new tabs in browser. My problem is that I need a POST request, not a GET one.

So I ask you for 2 suggestions: is there a way to import authenticated session such that Pyhon can make requests for websites that require auth?

If not, is there a way of doing something like this:

```py
webbrowser.open(url, new=0)
```

but with POST requests?

Thanks!

Comment: When you definitely need a webbrowser you could use a token, but for that you need to control the server, which might not be yours. Otherwise do as Mr.C proposed: Use the requests library.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mr. C, but alternatively...

Checkout [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). You can't make a direct POST request, but you can do anything that you would usually do as a normal user.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. Seems like you need more functionality than the webbrowser module provides.

Comment: Yes but I don't know if it's possible to make requests in browser with requests. I didn't find anything about that.

Comment: You need to use a requests session, login to the site (authenticate) with the session, and keep using it for eveything you need.